# declaredParameters versus addDeclaredParameter SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

So I'm working with an Oracle database and a function as opposed to a stored procedure. I figured this was no big deal and carried on as I had with all my previous DAO's created for the stored procedures. This did not work. The difference is demonstrated below.

Here's the function setup that works fine:

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.findClassYear = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                            .withSchemaName("CONNMAN")
                            .withFunctionName("F_CC_GET_STUCLASS")
                            .declareParameters(
                                    new SqlOutParameter("p_classout", Types.VARCHAR),
                                    new SqlParameter("p_pidm", Types.NUMERIC)
                            )
                            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();

    this.findClassYear.setAccessCallParameterMetaData(false);
    this.findClassYear.setFunction(true);
}
```

versus the setup—akin to that of what I would have used for a stored procedure—that doesn't work:

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.findClassYear = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                            .withSchemaName("CONNMAN")
                            .withFunctionName("F_CC_GET_STUCLASS");

    this.findClassYear.setAccessCallParameterMetaData(false);
    this.findClassYear.setFunction(true);

    //in parameters
    this.findClassYear.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("p_pidm", Types.NUMERIC));

    //out parameters
    this.findClassYear.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlOutParameter("p_classout", Types.VARCHAR));
}
```

Both would execute fine in a JUnit test but only the first produces a real result. Why can't I use dynamically declared parameters for a function and/or is that the only thing responsible for this change? What else am I missing if anything?

Answer (score 0):

**Limitations of table-valued parameters**

There are several limitations to table-valued parameters:

1. You can't pass table-valued parameters to user defined functions.
2. Table-valued parameters can only be indexed to support UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraints. SQL Server doesn't maintain statistics on table-valued parameters.
3. Table-valued parameters are read-only in Transact-SQL code. You
   can't update the column values in the rows of a table-valued
   parameter and you can't insert or delete rows. To modify the data
   that is passed to a stored procedure or parameterized statement in
   table-valued parameter, you must insert the data into a temporary
   table or into a table variable.

4 -You can't use ALTER TABLE statements to modify the design of
table-valued parameters.

5- You can stream large objects in a table-valued parameter.

Source: [Microsoft Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16#limitations-of-table-valued-parameters)